# Run java project via jsp page

Tags: jsp

Is there a way that I can run a whole java project via jsp?

I have a java project, now I want to make a jsp page which run my java project, then print "Completed!!", I don't even know if it could do that. Maybe I should make that project a .jar file, then run it? But I don't know how to do it either.

Can anyone please tell me how? It's better if jsp page can run a whole java project, if not, .jar file is good enough. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use AJAX and server-side code.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to call a Java function from Java code?

Comment: So, if someone opens a URL on your server which points to your JSP, the JSP should start the java program on your server and show the client when it's done?